# Kendo UI Scheduler has two duplicate dates smashed together in the header

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I'm using the Kendo UI Scheduler widget inside of an angular app, and the header portion of the scheduler has two identical dates pressed together with no space. The dates displaying depend on which day/week/etc of the calendar I'm viewing.

The output HTML looks like this:

```
<div kendo-scheduler>
  <div class="k-header">
    <ul class="k-reset k-scheduler-navigation"
      <li class="k-state-default k-header k-nav-today">...</li>
      <li class="k-state-default k-header k-nav-prev">...</li>
      <li class="k-state-default k-header k-nav-next">...</li>
      <li class="k-state-default k-nav-current">
        <a role="button" class="k-link" href="#">
          <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar"></span>
          <span class="k-sm-date-format" data-bind="text: formattedShortDate">8/5/2015 - 8/12/2015</span>
          <span class="k-lg-date-format" data-bind="text: formattedDate">Wednesday, August 05, 2015-Wednesday, August 12, 2015</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the bottom two spans inside of the last `<li>`. How do I remove one of them? I can't find a way to edit the header any where.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to add something like this to your page or style sheet.  Not necessarily the cleanest though.

```
<style>
    .k-sm-date-format{
        display:none;
    } 
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do.

**NOTE**: Do not hide 'k-sm-date-format' class, as in mobile devices, date will not be visible.

```
  function scheduler_databound(e) {
                        //hide dual date kendo error.
                        $('.k-lg-date-format').hide();
                }

            $(".scheduler").kendoScheduler({
                date: new Date(),
                height: 700,
                dataBound: scheduler_databound,
                views: [
                    "day",
                    { type: "month", selected: true },
                    "week",
                    "month",
                ],
                //timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                eventTemplate: $(".event-template").html(),
                editable: false,
                dataSource: result
            });
```